# How to take multiple sums, from multple tables and avoid cartesian product

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an internal time clock system for employees using php and phpmyadmin/sql. Keeping track of hours worked, lunch breaks and coffee breaks, all per day. there can by multiple entries per day for each category. In the end, I need to create a summary report for any given week. The report pulls from 4 different tables in phpmyadmin as layed out below.

I have tried a lot of things and searched alot of places. But I can not work past the cartesian product.

```
Tables:
Employee Table:

EmployeeID | First name | Last name |

Hours Table:

Clock ID  | Employee ID | ClockIN | Clock Out | Year | WeekID | Mon |...|Sun

auto      | number       | unix    | unix     | numb | numb   | unix

Lunch Table:

Clock ID |Employee ID|ClockIN|Clock Out|Year| WeekID | Mon |...|Sun|HoursID

auto      | number   | unix  | unix    |numb| numb   | unix|........| Numb

Clock Table: (used for break times)

Clock ID |Employee ID|ClockIN|Clock Out|Year| WeekID | Mon |...|Sun|HoursID

auto      | number   | unix  | unix    |numb| numb   | unix|........| Numb
```

I have tried so many different variations, i've lost track. Here was my last attempt, just to make it work for mondays.

```
$sql= 
"SELECT 

Employee.FirstName,
Employee.LastName,
Employee.EmployeeID,


            Hours.EmployeeID,
            Hours.Year,
            Hours.WeekID,
            Hours.ClockID,

            sum(Hours.Mon) as mon,


            Clock.HoursID
            sum(Clock.Mon) as MonBreak

            Lunch.HoursID
            sum(Lunch.Mon) as MonLunch



FROM
Employee, Hours, Clock


WHERE 
 Employee.EmployeeID = Hours.EmployeeID
 AND Hours.Year = '$dt_year' AND Hours.WeekID = '$dt_week'  
AND Clock.HoursID = Hours.ClockID

GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Employee.FirstName
";
```

Essentially I am looking to create this table in the end.

```
Employee Name | Mon Hours | Mon Lunch | Mon break | Tues........Sun Break|

Employee 1    | sum hours | sum lunch | sum break |...............

Employee 2    | sum hours | sum lunch | sum break |...............

Employee 3    | sum hours | sum lunch | sum break |...............
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It would probably help if you post a DBFiddle with some sample data in it.    This is one I use a lot https://www.db-fiddle.com  Note you can do a query `SHOW CREATE TABLE $table` to output the create table statement from your DB and paste it into the fiddle ... :-)  Just briefly looking at it, it's too complex for me to do in my head, maybe someone else can do it...

Comment: As far as this `But I can not work past the cartesian product` you probably don't want to work past it and I am not sure that is what you are seeing (typical of Many to Many, but not One to Many).  What I mean is that a single person could have multiple clock in and clock out for a single day.  Which means for each "person" row you could have "n" rows from any of the One to Many tables. There is also a lot of "duplication" in your tables, for example `Lunch Table` and `Clock Table` are Identical, and not much different then `Hours Table`if you could combine the tables it would greatly simplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get data except for the week days:

```
select t2.EmployeeID, EmployeeName, MonHours, lunchtotal + sum(Clock.ClockOut - Clock.ClockIn) as MonBreak
from
(
select t.EmployeeID, EmployeeName, MonHours, sum(Lunch.ClockOut - Lunch.ClockIn) as lunchtotal
from
(
select Employee.EmployeeID concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as EmployeeName, sum(Hours.ClockOut - Houts.ClockIn) as MonHours
from Employee
join Hours on Employee.EmployeeID = Hours.EmployeeID
group by Employee.EmployeeID
) t
join Lunch on t.EmployeeID = Lunch.EmployeeID
group by t.EmployeeID
) t2
join Clock on t2.EmployeeID = Clock.EmployeeID
group by t2.EmployeeID
```

You can further work out your way to differentiate week days as well, using [DAYOFWEEK](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php) and [case syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp). You will need to use those and wisely combine them with the sum.